# Headless RasPi. How to connect to wifi at new customer

Tags: raspberry-pi, network-programming

I have a raspi medical instrument which monitors xxx every minute or so and sends the reading to my www server. It all works well except the part at first installation where the customer enters his wifi credentials into the raspi. I really do **not** want to know his wifi or password.

I need some way for the customer to enter his wifi and password at his location, and without me being able to know the wifi and password.

How have others solved this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set the Pi up to be an access point and then ask him for the WiFi details to create wpa_supplicant.conf in /boot, remove the AP config and reboot.

If you are not up to creating that code you could use the Balena WiFi code from GITHUB [(code here)](https://github.com/balena-io/wifi-connect) if the licence fits your use case.

Comment: Thanks very much. I'll report on progress with a Raspi Zero.